# space between paragraphs (what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: html, css, text, fonts, paragraph

I have a table and inside of it I have a cell which has text. The text is one title and one short paragraph. When pressing enter to separate the title from the other text the space is really huge. 
What am I doing wrong? I tried replacing "p" with "br" and it worked but then I couldn't separate the different font styles.

```
<td width="373" valign="top" style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman',Times, serif; font-size:10px; line-height:12px">
    <p style="font-size:12px">MAIN TITLE<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mollis elit in lobortis interdum. Morbi gravida scelerisque ultrices. Suspendisse eget felis efficitur, porttitor tellus eget, euismod metus. Nullam id pellentesque quam, quis ultrices ipsum. Aenean orci purus, ultrices vel tincidunt sed</p>
</td>
```

**WHAT I HAVE :**

MAIN TITLE

(HUGE SPACE)

(HUGE SPACE)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit...etc

**WHAT I WANT:**

MAIN TITLE (STYLE: BOLD)

(ONE LINE)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit...etc (NOT BOLD)

Comment: Why is your content inside of a `<table>`? If you take out the `<br />` elements! and use margins to space your content it may behave better.

Comment: `<br><br>` is going to give you 2 line breaks

Comment: I am making a newsletter so the table is necessary. I want inside this cell to have a title and the text separated with a simple line and not just a huge space.

Comment: This looks like a comprehensive CSS tutorial:  http://www.cssbasics.com/introduction-to-css/  ~  I have not verified its accuracy yet, however, you can use the [W3C Validator](http://w3.org/) and [Mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org/) for that.

Comment: Guys it looks that this is easy for you. If it is then can you help me with the code instead of directing me to things I won't understand? I don't know what to change in css ( I don't even know how to view the css code). I tried to fix the problem by replacing the content with another table 2 by 1. The problem is that the inner table doesn't much the height of the cell. If I increase the tables height then I get the outside cell messed up. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea of css coding and yet I found my answer over the internet:

```
<style>
p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify my answer. People should see that no one provided an actual help and they treated like this is a teaching class.